# Am i using coroutine the correct way?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I launch a coroutine block inside the viewmodel.

First,  I fetch simple data from the database (for example plants with its ID and name etc...)

Second, I want to fetch the plants profile picture asynchronously.

```
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val plantList = plantScreenRepository.getPlants() // this is a suspend function
        val plantProfilePicList = mutableListOf<Deferred<Pair<String, Bitmap>?>>()
        plantList.forEach { plant ->
            val plantDeferred =
                async { plantScreenRepository.getProfilePicture(plantId = plant.plantId) }
            plantProfilePicList.add(plantDeferred)
        }
        val profilePictureList = plantProfilePicList.awaitAll()
        _plantList.value = buildList {
            plantList.forEach { plant ->
                val profilePicture = profilePictureList.firstOrNull { idAndPic ->
                    idAndPic?.first == plant.plantId
                }?.second
                add(
                    Pair(
                        plant,
                        profilePicture
                    )
                )
            }
        }.toMutableList()
    }
```

I tried changing the async's Dispatcher (IO, Default) but it didn't really speed up the process.

I know that now all async calls happen on the main Thread.

After i changed the Dispatcher to IO, the Thread changed but the speed was the same or a little bit slower.

Isn't changing the Dispatcher to IO supposed to speed up the process since all downloading process happen on a differente Thread?

Answer (score 1):

Dispatching with Dispatchers.IO *should* make it run in parallel if you do it like this (I cleaned it up a bit):

```kotlin
viewModelScope.launch {
  val plantList = plantScreenRepository.getPlants() // this is a suspend function
  _plantList.value = plantList.map { plant -> async(Dispatchers.IO) {
    val picture = plantScreenRepository.getProfilePicture(plantId = plant.plantId) 
    Pair(plant, picture.second)
  }}.awaitAll()
}
```

But it'll still wait until *all of the images* are loaded before showing even one of them which might be why you still think it's too slow.

So you might want to hold a `StateFlow<List<Pair<Plant, StateFlow<Bitmap>>>>` instead of a `StateFlow<List<Pair<Plant, Bitmap>>>` in your view model. That way images can be shown as they are loaded which will feel much more responsive. (The nested type is getting ugly so I'd define a new type instead of using pair and putting all the logic in the view model though)

An even better approach is to just let the view handle loading images but that wouldn't really answer your question.

Answer (score -1):

> I tried changing the async's Dispatcher (IO, Default) but it didn't really speed up the process.

How did you measure this? Did you measure in `release` mode? What are the measurements?

> I know that now all async calls happen on the main Thread.

What?

> After i changed the Dispatcher to IO, the Thread changed but the speed was the same or a little bit slower.

See first questions on how you measured this and what the values were.

> Isn't changing the Dispatcher to IO supposed to speed up the process since all downloading process happen on a differente Thread?

Not necessarily. You'll incur some overhead from the context switch. You may also be confusing *concurrency* with *parallelism*.

Coroutines run concurrently - they don't necessarily run in parallel.

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-mobile-concurrency-and-coroutines.html#asynchronous-vs-parallel-processing